# Literal object function scope, how to pass function & context to a 3rd

Tags: javascript

I have this callback 'machine': 
It is designed as object literal.

```
APC.UTIL.Callback = {
    nn: 0,
    step: 0,
    Myargs: null,
    that: null,
    internal: function () {
        var the_f = that.Myargs[that.step];
        if (that.step < that.nn) the_f(that.internal);
        else {
            the_f();
            that.Myargs = null;
        }
        that.step++;
    },
    loop: function () {
        this.Myargs = arguments;
        this.nn = this.Myargs.length - 1, this.step = 0;
        that = this;
        this.internal();
    },
}
```

And I use it so :

```
 var F1 = function (loop_back) { ... bla bla ; loop_back(); }
 var F2 = function (loop_back) { ... bla bla ; loop_back(); }
 var F3 = function (loop_back) { ... bla bla ; loop_back(); }
 var F4 = function (loop_back) { ... bla bla ; loop_back(); }

 // -------------------------------------------------------
 APC.UTIL.Callback.loop(F1,F2,F3,F4);
```

The callback calls itself the firstime, internal. Then F1 receives the function to later use it and call 'internal' again, F2, etc ....
( F1 F2 F3 are stored into Myargs array.)

The known problem... that or this (scope) is missing.
At the second call ' that' becomes to value null again....

I'd want a clean solution for the functions called.
I would not like to write more code in these.
var F1 = function (loop_back) { ... bla bla ; loop_back(); }
As you can see I write only the loop_back argument as a parameter and the I use it to make the callback.

I think my case is something special and different from the questions related with scope & object literal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems convoluted, I'm not sure what you mean by "callback machine". Could you post a real world example, and what the inputs/outputs look like?

Comment: @elclanrs The code is fine just as it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the stepping in the wrong place, it will never be reached if you invoke it **after** a loopback call.

```
var example = {
    nn: 0,
    step: 0,
    Myargs: null,
    that: null,
    internal: function () {
        var the_f = that.Myargs[that.step];
        if (that.step < that.nn) {
            that.step++;
            the_f(that.internal);
        } else {
            // ...this method expects a function as a parameter.
            the_f(function(){});
            that.Myargs = null;
        }
        // will never be reached
        // that.step++;
    },
    loop: function () {
        this.Myargs = arguments;
        this.nn = this.Myargs.length - 1, this.step = 0;
        that = this;
        this.internal();
    },
}
var F1 = function (loop_back) { console.log("F1"); loop_back(); }
var F2 = function (loop_back) { console.log("F2"); loop_back(); }
var F3 = function (loop_back) { console.log("F3"); loop_back(); }
var F4 = function (loop_back) { console.log("F4"); loop_back(); }

example.loop(F1, F2, F3, F4);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I had not thought into the reaching problem .!!

Comment: @civiltomain It may be reached but the timing will be bad for the loopbacks, hence it will "never" be reached in that context. The same actually goes for `that.Myargs = null;`